# How can I serialise a javabean to be loaded by Spring's DataBinder?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, properties, javabeans

I need to serialise a javabean (with arbitrary nested beans) to plain text, and then later restore as an Object graph.

For the purposes of this question I am not interested in XML, JSON, etc. but rather name/value pairs.

The [Spring DataBinder](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html) is great for turning a list of name/value pairs into a real Object. For example we can supply:

```
values.addPropertyValue("id", "6789");
values.addPropertyValue("nestedBean[0].systemId", "FOO");
values.addPropertyValue("nestedBean[1].systemId", "BAR");
```

And use the DataBinder to produce a top level bean (with property `id`) containing a `List` of two nested beans.

My question is, how can I easily serialise a bean into the format that DataBinder expects?

I would expect something of the form:

```
Map<String,String> reduceBeanToNameValuePairs(Object bean)
```

but have had no luck finding anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). Its [BeanMap](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) class provides an [entrySet](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html#entrySet()) method for accessing the wrapped bean's properties as entries of a map.

This functionality is already sufficient for "flat" beans and would probably provide a good starting point for adding the necessary recursion for nested bean graphs.